# Can the horseshoe prior be expressed analytically?

Tags: bayesian, prior, analytical

My question is about the horseshoe prior, [described by Carvalho et al.](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v5/carvalho09a/carvalho09a.pdf) It is specified as:

$$
\beta_i|\lambda_i,\tau\sim\mathcal N(0,\tau^2\lambda_i^2)\\
\lambda_i\sim\mathcal C^+(0,1)
$$

I have read a few sources (including [this question](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20exp%28-a%2Fx%5E2%29%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29%20dx%20from%200%20to%20infinity)) implying that the horseshoe prior cannot be expressed in closed form, that is, we cannot integrate over $\lambda_i$ and find a closed form expression for $f(\beta_i|\tau)$. However, [with some help from Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20exp%28-a%2Fx%5E2%29%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29%20dx%20from%200%20to%20infinity), I found this:

$$f(\beta_i|\tau)=\exp\left(\frac{\beta_i^2}{2\tau^2}\right)\text{erfc}\left(\left|\frac{\beta_i}{\tau\sqrt2}\right|\right)$$

Is this result correct? Is it considered a closed form expression? Also, can this be used to improve MCMC sampling, since one does not need to sample $\lambda_i$?

Thanks!

Edit: I am afraid this result is wrong because the original paper by Carvalho has a plot showing $f(\beta|\tau)\rightarrow\infty$ when $\beta\rightarrow0$, while the equation I got implies $f(\beta|\tau)\rightarrow1$. But I cannot find my error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal conditional density's normalizing constant is not free of lambda, so Wolfram is integrating the wrong thing.
$$
 (2\pi)^{-1}\int_0^\infty \underbrace{(2\pi\tau^2\lambda^2)^{-1/2}}_{\text{this part}}\exp\left[ - \frac{\beta^2}{2\tau^2\lambda^2} \right](1 + \lambda^2)^{-1} d \lambda.
$$